# Android half visible activity

Tags: android, view, android-3.0-honeycomb, viewflipper

I would like to ask you guys/girls, if somebody have any idea how i can achieve a two activity transition in honeycomb, where the the not used activity will be visible a quarter of the original size and the other activity will be place to the center. Also i need to mention i used activities smaller then the screen resolution with dialog theme to get them to the center.

I looked into the ViewAnimator, ViewSwitcher, ViewFlipper, but i`m not sure if can do that. (Sure need to override this classes)

Somebody have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two activities "active" at the same time so showing any proportion of one activity and another and interacting with both is not possible, if you don't care about interacting with both simultaneously you might look at the SlidingDrawer class, a lot of people have customized that.

It is possible to kind of fake what you are asking by using two layouts and changing their proportions/position at runtime, for instance you could have a layout that takes up the entire screen, then on some event it could be re-positioned/sized and a hidden layout shown.

That is if I am understanding your question correctly.

**Update**

Also have you looked at fragments?

Comment: Thx for your response. You understood very well, so don't need interaction in the not "active" activity. Yeah i`m using fragments in other parts of my project, but here i must implement some "overlay" feeling, so its complicating my life. I will try to customize the SlidingDrawer class. thx for your suggestion